# PHPMyAdmin exporting feature does not work with MySQL union table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In MySQL we can create a union table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO t1 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t1');
INSERT INTO t2 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t2');
CREATE TABLE total (
    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message CHAR(20), INDEX(a))
    ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

When I try to export data from main table "total" in PHPMyAdmin, select the csv format, it will always result into nothing.
But if I try to export data from sub tables "t1" or "t2" in PHPMyAdmin, also select csv format, it will work fine.

Is there anybody else ran into this issue. Is there some configuration in PHPMyAdmin or MySQL to workaround this situation?

PHPMyAdmin version 4.4.7

Comment: Will be fixed in 4.5.3 https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11732